# Growth Pattern of n^(m-n)

Tags: number-theory

Working on Project Euler, I arrived at [Task 99](https://projecteuler.net/problem=99):

Take a list of absurdly high numbers, written as base/exponent, and determine the highest one. The numbers are like 632382^518061 or 78864^613712.

I want to solve the task without actually calculating the numbers, hence I want to understand how exponents grow. I plotted the numbers 1^99, 2^98, 3^97...98^2, 99^1 and got a nice pattern with a maximum at 24^75.

y = x^(100-x)

[image: x^(100-x)=y]

However, I fail to generalize or explain this pattern. Can the maximum be calculated without actually calculating or plotting the graph?

Thanks.

Comment: $x \mapsto x^{100-x}$ is well defined as a function $f(x)$ of a positive _real_ number $x$, so you can find its maximum by usual differential calculus if you know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x^{100-x}$ Then rewrite
\begin{align}
y               &= x^{100-x} \\
\implies \ln y  &= (100-x) \ln x 
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} &= \left(\frac{100-x}{x}\right)-\ln x \\
\implies \frac{dy}{dx}   &= x^{100-x}\left( \left(\frac{100-x}{x}\right)-\ln x\right)
\end{align}
Points of inflexion occur at $$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ whence
\begin{align}
x^{100-x}\left( \left(\frac{100-x}{x}\right)-\ln x\right) &= 0
\end{align}
$\iff$

1. $x^{100-x}=0,\text{or}$
2. $\left(\frac{100-x}{x}\right)-\ln x = 0$

The first clause cannot be true. The second is true $\iff$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{100}{x} \right)-1 &=\ln x \\
\implies 100 &= x(1+\ln x)
\end{align}
Perhaps you could take it form here.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I would use logarithms:

log_b(x^y) = y*log_b(x) (any base)